# How do I revert a package update with yarn, including any extra files that appear after 'yarn add'?

Tags: yarnpkg, prisma

I am using prisma and had an issue where the engine download was stopping at 60% and just not downloading when I tried to migrate. I waited a few days and it randomly seemed to work suddenly. It downloaded the engine and i could use prisma.

I run `npx prisma format` and the command line recommends that i install the latest version of prisma. I did this thinking that the prisma engine wouldn't be overwritten by the package update, but it seems to have been.

This means i had to reinstall the prisma engine, but im getting that original problem again.

Is there a way for me to revert the package update and recover these engine files that appear separately to the package install when running a prisma command? Does yarn/npm record the state of the node_modules folder before a package update?

**I want to clarify that I do not want to simply downgrade my prisma version. I know how to do this. But this will not solve my original problem.**

I haven't yet tried anything because I'm not sure if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to my original Prisma version did actually seem to work. Prisma must store an engine for each version that you have used on your system, I would guess, so it didn't need to download it again.